# PHP, XML: How can duplicate nested objects be deleted?

Tags: php, xml, object, nested, simplexml

If there is an xml file that contains the following, how can the duplicate objects be deleted? There doesn't appear to be a php simplexml function that will do it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cars>
  <car>
<year>2000</year>
<make>cheverolet</make>
<model>malibu</model>
</car>
  <car>
<year>2019</year>
<make>cheverolet</make>
<model>malibu</model>
</car>
  <car>
<year>2000</year>
<make>cheverolet</make>
<model>malibu</model>
</car>
</cars>
```

Comment: convert it to an array and then remove dupes, then convert to XML?

Comment: which you can still remove dupes from ..

Comment: It converts to a 3 dimensional array.

Comment: See comment above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SimpleXML will work and you can use `unset()`  to remove the items, here I store the ones already found in an array and check before either removing it or adding it as a newly found combination.

The only complication is the usual thing of unsetting items in a list which you are modifying, so here I just keep `$carPos` to point to the actual item in the list and only increment it when I find a unique one.  This uses `xpath()` to find the list of cars to look at so that the list is kept independent of the list being modified...

```
$found = [];
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

$carPos = 0;
foreach ( $xml->xpath("//car") as $key => $car )   {
    $carType = (string)$car->year.",".(string)$car->make.",".(string)$car->model;
    if ( isset ( $found[$carType]) )    {
        unset ($xml->car[$carPos]);
    }
    else    {
        $found[$carType] = true;
        $carPos++;
    }
}
```